# query filter for mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have two collection one is questions which stores  _id, title, options, result, feedback and second is a child in the child I have store question_id, score. And I have filter the _id from questions collection. I don't know how I do this, Is it possible can we set the query for this. so that next time when I find the question from questions collection it sends filtered question. Means Return only that question from questions collection which id not same as the second collection child qustion_id.

This is my first collection where I have store questions, _id title option result feedback

```
        _id:{type:String},
        title:{type:String, required:true},
        options:{type:Array, required:true},
        result:{type:Array, required:true},
        feedback:{type:String}
```

This is my Second collection where I have store attempted question_id and score

```
    quiz:[
        {
             questionId:{
            type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Question',
            index: true
                    },
            score:{type:Number},
            time:{type:String}
            }
           ]
```

This is not exactly I just create an example

```
var query = {}
firstcollection.find($and[{_id:},{secondcollection question_id:}]},function(err, data){

so that filter data means filter _id will store in data.
and I send this data to the frontend

res.send(data);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The main problem is conceptual, you are trying to work with mongodb, which is document store in RDBMS style. Under the community pressure Mondo added some minimal join functionality in latest version, but it doesn't make it relational DB.

There is no good way to perform such query. The idea behind document store is simple - you do have collection of documents and you query this collection, and only this collection. All link between collections are "virtual" and only provided by code logic, with no support from DB engine.

So all you can do with mongo is: query first collection for ids (with appropriate projection, to fetch ids only), store answer to some array and then perform second query to other collection using this array.

Comment: thanks for reply sir, but there is any module or so technic to fetch value via query